# Regex Tag and short Text

Tags: php

I have some Problem with the output of my Code

```
$regex = '/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/si';
preg_match($regex, $products_description, $description);
$p1 = strpos($description, ' ', 200);
$p2 = substr($description, 0, $p1);
$content = $p2[1];
```

I want to get between a Tag the Text and short it to 200 characters. I dont know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: **What does "problem" mean?** "Problem" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: There is no any result. Nothing returns

Answer (score 0):

I got it working

```
//Find between a Tag the Text
$regex = '/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/si';
preg_match($regex, $products_description, $description);

//Short Text to max 150 characters
$p2 = substr($description[1], 0, 150);
$content = $p2;
```